# Why is my mint function adding an extra gwei to mints?

Tags: web3js, etherscan, nft, payable, mint

I have been testing out my NFT smart contract on Rinkeby to test out interaction on the front end. I have done many testnet mints with this same function, but the last two times that I have tried the function, it fails with this `Fail with error 'Incorrect payable amount'.` This error makes sense as etherscan shows the sender sending .6000000000000001 ether. The transaction will fail because of this line of code in my main mint function `require(msg.value == mintPrice * amount, "Incorrect payable amount");`. This error only seems to occur when I change the price and use the public mint function after I use my whitelist mint function. I am just wondering if there is a bug in my code somewhere or if this is definitely an error coming from the frontend. Another thought is should I change that require line to `msg.value >= mintPrice * amount`? Or could that create problems for potential buyers when minting?  [Here](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xE86d8E423800c361aA5f17Ac4F1B8364dfBf099f#code) is the link to the smart contract code if you would like to look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed to be a bug with the frontend code.